# Send message to particular user by Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, messenger

I am new in Facebook integration work.  I am working on one project by which i have to send a text message to fixed user (admin) , I already check several question/answer but i am not able to get exact answer.  Thank u in Advance

Comment: You could perhaps “abuse” the messenger platform subscription messaging feature for that. This is not a use case they would approve in review, but as long as you only need it to work for users that have a role in the app, that should work. But that’s about the only way to achieve that; there is no API to just send chat messages between users.

Comment: OK , Thank u for replying. I think i have to find another way to achieve this @CBroe

Answer (score 1):

If your bot installed to a Page, and if you know the user id of the admin then you can send many messages that user only. But, user id is not the same user id of Facebook user id. When someone creates a conversation with your bot, you can get the unique user id of that user for your bot. Please note that this user id is only for your bot, and it is different for other bots.